# os.walk() error - too many values to unpack

Tags: python

Hi I got a folder with color images in folder a that I want to change them to gray-scale images and save in folder b

```
from PIL import Image 
import os
# Changing image to gray and scaling to 256x128
WORK_DIR = 'D:/folder/data/' #working folder 

source = WORK_DIR + 'a'
target = WORK_DIR +'b'

for dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        image_file = Image.open(os.path.join(dirpath, file))
        image_file.draft('L', (256, 128)) #convert to gray and 256x128
        image_file.save(os.path.join(target, file))
```

I received below error, I am not sure what it means and how can I fix it?

```
----> 7 for dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
      8         for file in filenames:
      9                 image_file = Image.open(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a **3-tuple** (dirpath, dirnames, filenames)." from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: cv2 might be better than PIL for this, if you're able to use a different library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have gotten this error because os.walk() returns 3 items in a tuple (root, directories, files).

Just change

```
for dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
```

to

```
for root, dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
```

as Dan d. pointed out, you should change

```
os.path.join(dirpath, file)
```

to

```
os.path.join(root, file)
```

Comment: Thank you. I also removed the "/" from `WORK_DIR = 'D:/folder/data/'` so the data type is correct. However, I didn't get any pictures in the target folder, neither error messages

Comment: does WORK_DIR + 'b' exist?  If not, you can do os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True).  It will create one if not already done and ignore if it does exist.

Also you shouldn't remove that '/' since you are going to be adding 'b' and 'a' to it.

Comment: do source = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'a') and target = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'b')  then os.makedirs(target, exist_ok=True)

Comment: Don't forget to change `os.path.join(dirpath, file)` to `os.path.join(root, file)`.